# Siunitx does not let me use letter e

Tags: tables

I am using siunitx to align the decimals in a table. The problem is that for some reason it does not let me input the letter `e`. Other letters, such as `a` are fine.

Here is the code I am using.

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}c S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1] @{}}

header & a & e \\
a & 32.4 & 12.2 \\
c & 0.1  & 3.4 \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here is what I get. I was expecting to see both `a` and `e` in the header row. However, I only get `a`.

[image: Letter e does not appear in the table header.]

The only error message I get is `Invalid numerical input 'e'`. How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Use `{a}` and `{e}` in the header.

Comment: Wow, that works. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Escape all non-numeric input in `S`columns with braces: ```header & {a} & {e} \\```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`siunitx` parses the contents of a column of type `S` unless the option `parse-numbers=false` was set -- which isn't the case in the code snippet you posted. For this reason, the letters `d`, `e`, and `j` will cause a crash unless they're encountered in numeric expressions such as `1e5`, `2d7`, or `-j`. (In the third example, `j` is taken to be a way to encode the imaginary number, aka `i`.) Depending on the circumstances, the letter `g` can also be interpreted to have a special meaning.

`siunitx` has become smart enough in recent years to be able to figure out that inputs such as `cat` and `fly` cannot possibly represent numbers and hence should be treated as pure text. This smartness is, incidentally, the reason why `a` in one of the cells of your code snippet doesn't cause a problem. However, since it isn't all that challenging to write `{cat}` and `{fly}`, do make a habit of encasing non-numeric terms -- they occur rather frequently in the header cell(s) of `S` columns... -- in curly braces. That way, you're sure to have eliminated all uncertainty about how text in header cells should be processed.